# Can I log employees' working hours through Bonjour availability?

Tags: bonjour

We have a small office network with a Mac server, and all employees have their own Mac laptop they take home at the end of the day.

I am looking for a way to automatically log the employees' time at the office. Theoretically, it should be possible to periodically check for other auto-discovered Bonjour hosts on the network and deduce their time at the office from there.

Now my question is, is there an app or other readily available solution for that?

**EDIT:**

I should note that the users don't actually log in to the network nor log out. Their computers are not part of an Open Directory. I also really don't want to install or access anything on their computer directly.

I want to log their presence purely based on listening for their network presence. I also don't want to manually manage a list of computers, computers should be tracked automatically once they are discovered on the network.

At the end of the week/month I want to be able to get a list of all connected computer names during that period, with the time periods they were connected. Some graphical representation similar to day-view in iCal would be perfect, but if I have this information textual I could always implement that part myself.

**EDIT 2:**

I've been doing some research myself and found out about the dns-sd tool. For example:

```
dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp local
```

lists all computers with AFP enabled.

However, two problems:

- the dns-sd utility from the command-line is not well suited for scripts, the man page recommends against it, the command also doesn't terminate itself
- The above example does not work when AFP file sharing is disabled

Comment: Good question!!! I like it!

Comment: I have an mDNS module for node.js that I could post up on github if you were interested.

Comment: @DickHardt If that could be a possible solution I'm more than interested!

Comment: If you are simply asking if it is possible… YES, it is. (as is almost everything in this world), but you either need to hire a developer, or learn about dns-sd and writing scripts / software that supports it, as I doubt there is anything off the shelf for this...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want something like [NetSpy](http://www.net-monitoring-software.com/) or [ActyMac](http://www.actymac.com/) to monitor employee activity. It will handle what you want and more, although I'm not sure I would suggest the orwelian approach to employee management.

You may want to look into a pure network monitoring tool like [Paessler](http://www.paessler.com/network_monitoring_tool).

The easiest solution would be for you to just monitor the server log on your OS X server for the time the user logs-in and logs out. A simple script that tracks the time and totals them into a spreadsheet using a nightly cron job.

You can also just use the [last](https://superuser.com/questions/65375/user-login-log-on-mac-os-x) command as seen in the screenshot aslong as the file has not be cleared.

[image: Console Example]

You may want to try other basic unix system logging scripts.

Comment: Thank you, some nice suggestions, but not exactly what I was looking for yet. I'll clarify some points by editing my question.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into a network monitoring tool like [Motadata](https://www.motadata.com/product/network-management-and-monitoring/network-monitoring/)

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer to explain how exactly this tool can be used to solve the problem described in the question?